# How do we describe the right adjoint?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory

I am interested in the category-theoretic description of trees (and operads?) and have started a course of study that will allow me to engage with these two ([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.2874.pdf), [2](http://mat.uab.cat/%7Ekock/cat/polynomial.pdf)) manuscripts of Joachim Kock.

An essential prerequisite to the early portions of the manuscript involves an understanding of a pair of adjoint functors. The left adjoint is the change of basis functor $g^{\ast}: \mathbf{Set}_{/A} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}_{/B}$ associated with the change of basis between sets $g: B \rightarrow A$. I find it very easy to reason about the image of a bundle under the change of basis functor. This functor takes a bundle $f: X \rightarrow A$ to the pullback of $f$ by $g$, which I can easily interpret in $\mathbf{Set}_{/B}$ as the fibered product with the canonical projection $h: X \times_{A} B \rightarrow B$ given by $h: (x, b) \mapsto b$.

Kock utilizes the right adjoint, which I have read is called the dependent product:
$$
  (g^* \dashv \prod_g)
  \colon
  \mathbf{Set}_{/B}
   \stackrel{\overset{g^* }{\leftarrow}}{\underset{\prod_g}{\to}}
  \mathbf{Set}_{/A}
  \,.
$$

I am trying to understand this functor, but am finding it very difficult. Are there any set-theoretic descriptions of the image of a bundle $f: X \rightarrow B$ under $\prod_g$ that would help me in this context?

Although I've only had a little exposure to it, the process of re-describing adjoint functors in the "internal language of their categories" (I hesitate to use this phrase here-- I have seen it used in the literature of toposes and do not know its formal definition-- perhaps I'll just call this process *reifying*?) has proven very difficult for me. Are there any mental algorithms that offer any help? Are there a set of useful exercises I can undertake to develop the skill? Are there theorems I can study that will provide insight into the process?

It has struck me in the course of mulling over the problem that I would also like to know whether category-theorists even bother with reifying their constructions. Does this process have a name? Is it done often?

Comment: A sequence of exercises that may give insight into the process of "reification": 1. For an object $X$ in $\operatorname{Set}/A$ and an element $a\in A$, show that the preimage of $a$ may be identified with $\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Set}/A}{a,X}.$ 2. Use this description and the definition of right adjoint to compute the fibers of the dependent product.

Comment: It may be helpful to explain what your background is. For me, coming from an algebraic geometry/sheaf-theory background, I look at this and I see that you're asking for the right adjoint of a pullback, so the answer should look like a pushforward. But different fields talk about similar notions in different language, and so the most helpful answer may be from someone who speaks your language. (BTW, most but not all category-theorists do have in mind explicit models of their constructions.)

Comment: @dhy it's a question about sets, so one can write down a fairly concrete description.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I'm afraid I don't see how this is related to my comments. I agree there is a fairly concrete description - it is provided by my first comment, no? I wrote it down in the form of a sequence of exercises because the question asked for insight into the thought processes involved, and I thought that doing those exercises was the easiest way to gain that insight.

Comment: Sure, but talking about pushforward, sheaves and algebraic geometry may not be helpful at this point. And by "provided", I see you gave a hint. :-)

Comment: That's fair; the point I was trying to make was that every field has a list of "standard adjunctions", and that in practice these sorts of questions are often answered by comparing to those "standard adjunctions." But I see that my comment could easily be interpreted as "this way (via pushforwards & pullbacks) is the best way to think about it."

Comment: Hint: A good way to bootstrap this is first to consider the case where A=✱ is the set with a single element.  The general case can then be treated by applying the special case to both A and B.  Edit: As soon as I left this comment, David gave an answer that does exactly this! =].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's worth thinking about the simplest example, namely when $A$ is a single point. In this case, $g^*$ is the product functor $-\times B$, and its right adjoint is the set of sections: it sends $f\colon X\to B$ to the set $\Gamma(B,X)$ of sections $s\colon B\to X$ of $f$. This is vaguely similar behaviour to how the internal hom in a cartesian closed category is right adjoint to taking a product. In particular, if $X = Y\times B = g^*Y$, then $\Pi_g f = Y^B$.

The space of sections is the same thing as the product of all the fibres of $f$, so one can think of the general dependent product this way, now just parameterised by the elements of $A$. Given a point $a\colon *\to A$, which is an object of $\mathbf{Set}/A$, we can calculate
$$
\mathbf{Set}/A(a,\Pi_g f) \simeq \mathbf{Set}/B(B\times_A *,f) = \mathbf{Set}/B(g^{-1}(a),f)
$$
Now the latter is the set $\Gamma(g^{-1}(a),X)$ of sections of $f$ over $g^{-1}(a)\subset B$. But $\mathbf{Set}/A(a,\Pi_g f)$ is the fibre of $\Pi_g f \to A$ over $a$, so
$$
\Pi_g f = \coprod_{a\in A} \Gamma(g^{-1}(a),X) \to A.
$$

A similar mental picture works, to some extent, in categories that behave like the category of sets, except that you shouldn't think of $\Pi_g f$ as a disjoint union, but something more like a continuous family of spaces of sections. Note howoever, how I used the defining property that it was a right adjoint to get a handle on the construction. In general, one can use [generalised elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+element) in place of $1\to A$ to construct the thing, at least as a presheaf, and then knowing the dependent product exists means this is representable.